# Почему в классе родителе надо использовать метод super?

Tags: python

Почему так происходит, что если убрать `super().__init__()` в классе `Employee`, то `MixinLog` не сработает?

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class Employee(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, pay):
        print("Добавлен сотрудник")
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.pay = pay
        super().__init__()


class MixinLog:
    ID = 0

    def __init__(self):
        MixinLog.ID += 1
        print(f'Добавлен сотрудник с номером: {self.ID}')


class Developer(Employee, MixinLog):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, pay, prog_lang):
        print('Добавлен разработчик')
        super().__init__(name, surname, pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang


dev = Developer('Ivan', 'Ivanov', 100000, 'Python')
print(dev.__dict__)
print(Developer.__mro__)
```

Comment: Потому что больше не остаётся никаких причин, почему он должен был бы срабатывать

Answer (score 1):

`super()` позволяет вызывать методы родительского класса.
Когда вы внутри `Developer` пишите`super().__init__()` , вы вызываете инит родителя и тем самым выполняете код родительского `__init__`.

Если его убрать, получается, что нет больше причин для срабатывания `__init__` класса `MixinLog`

Comment: Спасибо огромное)))

Comment: @extract, если вам помог данный ответ, вы можете принять его, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.